# replacing of numbers to zero in a sum

Tags: python

I have to define a function `'func(a, b, c)'` in which there are 3 variables it calculates their sum. I have to check if there value is greater than `'13'` then the number becomes `'0'` eg.,

`'def func(3,4,14)'` ---> 7   (3+4+0)

I've tried this code below:

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  if(a>13):
      a=0
  elif(b>13):
      b=0
  elif(c>13):
      c=0
  return a+b+c
```

But it didn't work. Am I doing wrong somewhere?
Please suggest me the correct way to do it...

Comment: `if there value is greater than '13' then the number becomes '0'` doesn't make much sense. Also, your example also is not very clear.

Comment: Could you show how you call the function and what error you are getting

Comment: I simply want to make a number's value `'0'` to the sum, if it is greater than 13..

Comment: @GauravTomer has the below answer answered your question if not then comment on it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is using `elif`. You want to use `if`:

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
    if a > 13:
        a = 0
    if b > 13:
        b = 0
    if c > 13:
        c = 0
    return a + b + c
```

To create a general function you could use [`*args`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) in a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function):

```
def no_teen_sum(*args):
    return sum(arg if arg < 13 else  0 for arg in args)
```

Example:

```
>>>no_teen_sum(1, 2, 14)
3
```

Answer (score 5):

a version using `sum`:

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
    return sum( i if i <= 13 else 0 for i in (a, b, c))

print(no_teen_sum(1, 2, 3), no_teen_sum(1, 2, 13), no_teen_sum(11, 12, 13))
```

output:

```
6 16 36
```

can be easily adapted if you have to add more than 3 values this way:

```
def no_teen_sum(lst):
    return sum( i if i <= 13 else 0 for i in *lst)

print(no_teen_sum(11, 12, 13, 14, 15))
```